# How to use / reference a common library hosted on a network share in a .NET 6 application

Tags: configuration, .net-6.0

We have a library of utility functions that most of our current (.Net Framework 4.8) applications reference. Let's call it UsefulStuff.dll.
It is neither stored locally nor held in the GAC, it is referenced from one of our servers using a combination of dependentAssembly and codeBase settings in app.config.
For example:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="UsefulStuff" publicKeyToken="d7773b022d76a600" />
        <codeBase version="3.5.0.0" href="file:\\myserver\Shared\UsefulStuff.dll" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

We are planning to use .NET 6 going forward (I am just beginning my learning trek) and want to use a similar approach whereby non breaking changes to UsefulStuff.dll (a .NET 6 version) will be picked up by client applications from the central location.
From what I have been able to learn, "codeBase" isn't a .NET 6 thing so can you please help me understand how to achieve this functionality.

I have done extensive searching of the web but haven't been able come across anything that looks like my situation.

Thanks in advance.
John